# Extracting text from an alphanumeric reference

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a load of bank statement data which includes a payment reference. This is free form so some include invoice numbers, their info or a name and typically it’s 16-256 characters depending on the system they use to make the payment. I’ve put the data in a pandas data frame with transaction amount, currency and date but now want to get python to ‘read’ the reference and extract any words to put them in a new column. I know how to separate based on indexing but as the data is free form I just want to look for any letters wherever they occur. An example record would be:
15122021 Amazon ref 1021/1022

So the ideal would be to pick up that Amazon and ref are also separate words. Any help gratefully received!

I’ve not been able to work out how I can search only for letters

Comment: You should give a good reproducible example _as text and not just a single string_ to check if the column has a visible pattern and also a clear expected output in your dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Some more example references are:

Answer (score 0):

If the target text would always be one sequence of contiguous words, you could try using `str.extract` as follows:

```py
df["name"] = df["invoice"].str.extract(r'(\w+(?: \w+)*)')
```